# CakePHP reverse routing issues

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've been using routing with "slug" as a named parameter, for example:

```
Router::connect('/category/:slug',  array('controller'=>'categories', 'action'=>'view'), array('pass'=>array('slug'), 'slug'=>'[a-z0-9\-]+'));
```

I've now stumbled across a problem because I want to restrict the above route to logged in users only, so I've put this in the beforeFilter() function of my CategoriesController:

```
if(!$this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
    $this->Auth->deny('view');
}
```

Now if I go to /category/my-category (while logged out) I'll be redirected to my application's login page, unfortunately after I log in I'm redirected to /categories/view/my-category/slug:my-category

This is due to line 317 of AuthComponent.php, where we have:

```
$this->Session->write('Auth.redirect', Router::reverse($request));
```

So it seems when I do Router::reverse($request) on the above route it doesn't work properly (because it thinks "my-category" should be both a passed and a named parameter).

Is this a problem with the way I've set up this route, or is it a bug with CakePHP? Surely Router::reverse($request) should always return the URL we're currently at?

Any advice appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if it is a bug or not, but until we find out a work-around could be to manually set the new loginRedirect in your category controller like so:

```
if(!$this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
    $this->Auth->deny('view');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/categories/' . $this->request->params['slug'];
}
```

Note, check that `$this->request->params['slug']` is the right var to use, not 100% off the top of my head.